# How to show and hide if user is logged?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I create a composition template:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:cs="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composite">

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty userc.userb.user.id}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="Welcome, " />
            <h:outputLink value="profile.xhtml">
                <h:outputText value="#{userc.personb.person.name}" />
            </h:outputLink>

            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="#{userc.logout}">Log out</h:commandLink>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty userc.userb.user.id}">
        <h:outputLink value="pages/login.xhtml">Login</h:outputLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

My intention is to hide the first `panelGroup` if the user is not logged, if he does then I hide the second panelGroup then show the first one.

I'm trying do this but doesn't work.
Any idea ?

Without login:

[image: without login]

After login:

[with login http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/9866/0602nov.jpg](http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/9866/0602nov.jpg)

Comment: Look like it should work. What exactly happens instead? Add `<p>userb: "#{userc.userb}"</p><p>user: "#{userc.userb.user}"</p><p>id: "#{userc.userb.user.id}"</p>` to the view to debug one and other. This may give clues.

Comment: I update my post, I think when it cames the id = 0, it thinks that Is true, so that's why it show the panelGroup.
I'm should create a boolean as a flag to see if the user is logged or not, right ? I wonder if it is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `entity.User` class, replace

```
private int id;
```

by

```
private Integer id;
```

This way it will default to `null` instead of `0` and thus `#{empty userc.userb.user.id}` will be `true`. The common practice is anyway to use wrappers instead of primitives in entity's properties.

Comment: Yes, otherwise it's hard to tell for example `0` or `false` apart from being the default or user-entered value.